# Need to access a value in the HTML Table using xpath from PYTHON SELENIUM

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, xpath

I have a Web browser's app UI Table  as shown like this...

```
DATAPOINT           VALUE           STATUS
Output Voltage     95.0 VAC         Nominal
PS Input Voltage   15.0 VAC         Nominal
Inverter Status       Off           Nominal
Major Alarm        No Alarm         Nominal
Minor Alarm        No Alarm         Nominal
```

InnerHTML representation is something like this ...

```
tr[1] ---> td[1]      td[2]         td[3]
tr[2] ---> td[1]      td[2]         td[3]
tr[3] ---> td[1]      td[2]         td[3]
tr[4] ---> td[1]      td[2]         td[3]
tr[5] ---> td[1]      td[2]         td[3]
```

The above table is created by HTML Table like this ...

```
<table id="inventoryGrid1" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" style="width: 408px;">
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
      <td>Output Voltage</td>
      <td>95.0 VAC</td>
      <td>
        <img src="../img/led/led_green.png">
        <span> Nominal </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" role="row">
      <td>PS Input Voltage</td>
      <td>135.0 VAC</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
      <td>Inverter Status</td>
      <td>Off</td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" role="row">
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The Full xpath is ...

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
```

I need to know ...

1. I can't assign:
   **row2col3 = drv.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")** # attempting to assign a variable to element in the table( row 2 column 3) which is "Nominal"

   Throws error: as 'list' object has no attribute ...
   Is it displaying that *td tag name* is a list ? and hence can't assign to a single variable ? 
   Anyways, I am suppose to use **row2col3 = drv.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")** in order to get it working !
2. If I use the row2col3 element I neither can use row2col3.text nor row2col3.get_attribute("innerHTML"). So how do I get this ? Is it even possible ?

How do I read out row2col3 particularly from the table ?
Please forgive me for the long xpath implementation command and the bad english and also the long msg... :)

Comment: the 3rd td element of the 2nd tr element does not contain anything in your example -> did you forget to post sth? it's acutally not even closed correctly

Comment: When I copied the XPath from Firebug it was something like this for the second row and third column   ..../tr[2]/td[3] at the end. Do you think, I am missing something here ?

Comment: yeah I think you're missing something in the html you posted -> your first row has a 3rd td element with an image and span, but your second and third row only have the opening of the td element, but nothing follows ...

Comment: ohhh that.... there were similar tag name td elements with span. I just hid that coz it would make the post much bigger ! :) But the UI table mentioned top would clarify the same... td[1]  is associated to Datapoint, td[2] is associated to Value td[3] with span element would have STATUS. Every tr class is having the same sort of representation

Comment: ahh ok! So you want to extract the text "Nominal" or whatever is written in the other 2 span elements right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Is there a possible way to get this ?

Answer (score 0):

value = findElement.byXpath("//tr[@class='even']//td[2]").getValue()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I am not sure if this works like total expectation. I have tried this too. The reason is, every alternate tr row will have even or odd class, hence if I use this way; the list of tr in the even rows will only be considered !

Comment: try: 
//td[text()='PS Input Voltage']/../td[2]